# How to avoid json.dumps() to encode already encoded strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use a module that takes binary data and turns it into a Python dictionary.
I then parse this data to another Python dictionary structure.
Finally, I use json.dumps() to dump the records to disk.

I just discovered that this library encodes double-quoutes, and that the json library then escapes those escapes.

Imagine the following string: *Sean "Puff Daddy" Combs*

```
import json

record = some_binary_file_reading_module.read()
print(record["name") # prints "Sean \"Puff Daddy\" Combs"
my_new_record = create_new_record(record)
myfile.write(json.dumps(my_new_record) # output becomes "Sean \\"Puff Daddy\\" Combs"
```

How do I avoid this second escape? These records can contain all kinds of strings, so i assume this one is not the only escape. Do I have to write my own algorithm?

I have a similar example where reading data into csv.DictReader and then serializing values of this to json using json.dumps

Comment: The problem is the reading and conversion, not the json dumping. The json dumping ensures you end up with valid json, if you want a different output change the input (remove the explicit backslash if there actually is one) or write custom serialization that is no longer guaranteed to be valid json.

Comment: I added an edit to highlight this

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is consistent (and it sounds like it is), you can just replace it in the string:

```
my_string.replace('\\"', '')
```

Comment: Thank you. There are many patterns expected in these strings, so it would not hold.